# LOGIC APPS - Fetch all URLs from an outlook email trigger and create an array

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, text-extraction

In logic apps, from the trigger email block, the body will be extracted and stored in a variable in a HTML format. EMail will containt one or more image URLs. Task is to extract all the image URL and create an arrya and store. For each URL in the array, do some action with OneDrive.

Im currently stuck in fetching all the image URLs and store in an array. If anyone can suggest some solution will be helpful. Given below the sample email content

========================================================

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div dir="ltr">
         <br>
         <br>
         <div class="gmail_quote">
            <div dir="ltr" class="gmail_attr"><span style="color:rgb(80,0,80)">Images from&nbsp;&#43;9190020498901 to&nbsp;&#43;9191232615.</span><br></div>
            <div dir="ltr">
               <div class="gmail_quote">
                  <div dir="ltr">
                     <div class="gmail_quote">
                        <div dir="ltr">
                           <div class="gmail_quote">
                              <div dir="ltr">
                                 <div class="gmail_quote">
                                    <div dir="ltr">
                                       <div class="gmail_quote">
                                          <div dir="ltr">
                                             <div class="gmail_quote">
                                                <div dir="ltr">
                                                   <div class="gmail_quote">
                                                      <div dir="ltr">
                                                         <div>
                                                            <div style="color:rgb(80,0,80)"><br></div>
                                                            <a href="https://www.ema.europa.eu/sites/default/files/emabuilding2019_en_1.jpg" target="_blank">https://www.ema.europa.eu/sites/default/files/emabuilding2019_en_1.jpg</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                         </div>
                                                         <a href="https://www.se.com/ww/en/assets/564/media/44518/560/87591358-490x280.jpg" target="_blank">https://www.se.com/ww/en/assets/564/media/44518/560/87591358-490x280.jpg</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                      </div>
                                                      <a href="https://realtynxt.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/489.jpg" target="_blank">https://realtynxt.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/489.jpg</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div><br></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               -- <br>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br clear="all">
         <div><br></div>
         -- <br>
      </div>
      </div>
      <br clear="all">
      <div><br></div>
      -- <br>
      <div dir="ltr" class="gmail_signature">
         <div dir="ltr">Thanks
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any process on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use azure function connector to implement it. I write a local function and deploy it.

Below is my http trigger function return the url list.

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string query = req.Query["html"];

            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            Regex regex = new Regex("(?:href|src)=[\"|']?(.*?)[\"|'|>]+", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
            if (regex.IsMatch(query))
            {
                foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(query))
                {
                    list.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(list);
        }
```

Below is my logic app flow, store the html in the variable and pass it with query parameter.

[image]

Here is the result, suppose this is what you want.

[image]